# How to export google tag manager tags and triggers into Excel or Google sheet file?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have to do an audit for different Google tag manager accounts and I would like to export from their respective containers the tags and triggers into an excel or a google sheet file
Do you know if this is possible?

Please can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

I needed to do something similar today, so here's a script I quickly up with to extract the filters and their conditions to a CSV.

Simply run it in your console:

```
document.querySelectorAll('tr[gtm-table-row]').forEach(n => {
    const triggerName = n.querySelector('td:nth-child(2)').textContent.trim();
    const eventType = n.querySelector('td:nth-child(3)').textContent.trim();
    const triggerConditions = '"' + Array.from(n.querySelectorAll('td:nth-child(4) .gtm-predicate-summary-row')).map(conditionElement => conditionElement.textContent.trim()).join(',') + '"';

    console.log(`"${triggerName}", "${eventType}", "${triggerConditions}"`);
});
```

It's far from complete. I only tested it for the Triggers view, there's no pagination support, it's error-prone if you have double-quotes in your filter conditions, etc...

But that should help people who end up on this post to get started.

Comment: Looks like you're missing the closing ` in the console log.

Comment: Indeed, fixed! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Google Tag Manager API: https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/api/v2

You can manage tags and triggers. You can use Apps Script and relative Tag Manager Service to get info you want directly from a Spreadsheet: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/tag-manager

Comment: Thank you for this, it looks a bit complicated the set up  there is no an easiest way?

Comment: Apps Script is the easiest way, the authentication to the API is integrated and the flow is automatic.

Comment: @Marco Lucky for you the inestimable Simo Ahava has already build the sheet add-on for you: https://www.simoahava.com/tools/gtm-tools-by-simo-ahava/

Answer (score 0):

To add on to the accepted, I needed something similar and wanted to get all data from all the tags set up in our gtm.

- First thing you want to do is to make sure you scroll down (on tagmanager) and make sure that "Show Rows" has "All" as its selected option. You should now be able to see all of your tags.
- Next, open up your console and put in the following script:

  ```
    document.querySelectorAll('tr[gtm-table-row]').forEach(n => {
    const triggerName = n.querySelector('td:nth-child(2)').textContent.trim();
    const eventType = n.querySelector('td:nth-child(3)').textContent.trim();
    const firingTriggers = Array.from(n.querySelectorAll('td:nth-child(4) .small-trigger-chip')).map(conditionElement => conditionElement.textContent.trim());
    const folder = n.querySelector('td:nth-child(5)').textContent.trim();
    const lastEdited = n.querySelector('td:nth-child(6)').textContent.trim();

    // To find if Tag is currently paused 
    const lastEditedClassNames = Array.from(n.querySelectorAll('td:nth-child(6)')[0].childNodes).filter(child => child.clientHeight > 0)
    const paused = lastEditedClassNames.length !== 0 

    const tag = {
        name: triggerName,
        type: eventType,
        Firing_Triggers: firingTriggers,
        Folder: folder,
        Last_Edited: lastEdited,
        Currently_Paused: paused
    }

    gtmData.push(tag)
  ```

  })
- Once you have that, you can type "gtmData" in the console and hit enter. It should print out all of your gtmData.
- Right click and copy the gtmData object.

From here the choice is yours. If you need to make it a csv then there are sites that will get that data changed for you. Hope this helps!